# How do you find the transition matrix when you're only given some cases?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I am trying to find the transition matrix of the linear transformation

\begin{align}
T = \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \text{ with }T(1,1,1) = (2,2,2), T(0,1,1) = (0,-3,-3), \text{ and }T(1,2,3) = (-1, -2, -3)
\end{align}

My idea of solving this is to find
\begin{align}
T(1, 0, 0) &= T(1,1,1) -T(0,1,1)\\
T(0, 1, 0) &= T(0,1,1) - T(0,0,1)\\
T(0, 0, 1) &= T(1,2,3) - T(1,1,1)-T(0,1,1)
\end{align}

And work with

\begin{align}
T(x,y,z) = xT(1,0,0) + yT(0,1,0) + zT(0,0,1)
\end{align}

To end up with a transition matrix. But I am not sure if this is a correct process, and I don't know how to find $T(0,1,0)$ with the given information as well.

Comment: Notice that having the image of a basis determines the transformation, so they are giving you the whole transformation, not just some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a perfectly valid approach.
You will basically write the coordinates of $T(1,0,0),\ T(0,1,0),\ T(0,0,1)$ in the columns of a matrix.

Observe that $(0,1,0)\ =\ (0,1,1)-(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Gosh why didn't I think of that? Thank you!